# How to instantiate an object of a type passed by parameter, that needs to implement a certain interface?

Tags: c#, types, interface, instantiation

Lets say I have an interface called IMyInterface, and a class called MyClass that implements IMyInterface

In another class I have a method that has a type as parameter and this type must implement IMyInterface to be valid. e.g. MyClass would be a valid argument. Then in the method I would instantiate an object of the type passed by parameter.

How would I achieve this? If not possible, what solution would have a similar effect?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're asking here. Are you asking how to construct an object of a `Type` object passed in, given that it refers to a class that implements a certain interface? Or are you asking how to verify that the passed `Type` object details a class that implements that interface? Please clarify.

Comment: I would like to know how to have a method that given a Type, constructs the type, but only if the type implements a certain interface. So its both questions I have to say. Sorry if I should have split them into two posts.

Comment: Then [@Vadim](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5649561/vadim-martynov) has already posted your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two parts of the answer. First you should validate type by [`Type.IsAssignableFrom`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isassignablefrom(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var implementInterface = (typeof(IMyInterface)).IsAssignableFrom(type);
if(!implementInterface)
    // return null, throw an exception or handle this scenario in your own way
```

Next you can instantiate an object. here are several ways you can create an object of a certain type on the fly, one is use [`Activator.CreateInstance`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wccyzw83.aspx):

```
// create an object of the type
var obj = (IMyInterface)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
```

And you'll get an instance of MyClass in obj.

Another way is to use reflection:

```
// get public constructors
var ctors = type.GetConstructors(BindingFlags.Public);

// invoke the first public constructor with no parameters.
var obj = ctors[0].Invoke(new object[] { });
```

And from one of ConstructorInfo returned, you can "Invoke()" it with arguments and get back an instance of the class as if you've used a "new" operator.

Comment: That is exactly what I needed. I tested and it worked perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: Ok, first time it worked, but then later it didn't work anymore, I must have not tested appropriately, because I figured I should be using "typeof(IMyInterface).IsAssignableFrom(type);" instead of "type.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(IMyInterface));". The conditions for it to be true are listed here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isassignablefrom(v=vs.110).aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396&cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1

one of them says "The current instance is an interface that c implements."

So I suppose the interface must be the one who calls the method.